# How to construct a concrete sequence $\{(a_i,b_i]\}$ such that the inequality $\sum_i(F(b_i)-F(a_i)) < \epsilon$ holds for all $\epsilon>0$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, measure-theory, proof-writing

I got stuck on the following problem:

> Let $F:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a bounded, nondecreasing, and right-continuous function that satisfies $\lim_{x\to-\infty}F(x)=0$. Define a function $\mu^*:\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})\to[0,+\infty]$ by letting $\mu^*(A)$ be the infimum of the set of sums $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(F(b_n)-F(a_n))$, where $\{(a_n,b_n]\}$ ranges over the set of sequences of half-open ivtervals that cover $A$, in the sense that $A \subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_n,b_n]$. Prove that $\mu^*(\emptyset) = 0$.

I would like to show it in this way:

> For each positive number $\epsilon$ there is a sequence $\{(a_i,b_i]\}$ of half-open intervals (whose unions necessarily includes $\emptyset$) such that $\sum_i(F(b_i)-F(a_i)) < \epsilon$.

However, I failed to give a concrete argument showing that the above claim is true; for example, I couldn't construct such a concrete sequence $\{(a_i,b_i]\}$ such that the inequality $\sum_i(F(b_i)-F(a_i)) < \epsilon$ holds for all $\epsilon>0$.

Could someone please help me out? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By right continuity there exists $a_n \in (0,1)$ such that $F(n+a_n)-F(n)<\frac  {\epsilon} {2^{n+1}}$. $\sum_n [F(n+a_n)-F(n)]<\epsilon$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'd like to confirm if my understanding is correct. Basically, we may define the sequence $\{(a_i,b_i]\}$ of half-open intervals as follows: Let $a_i = i$ and $b_i=a_i+c_i$ where $\{c_i\}$ is a sequence of positive numbers converging to $0$ such that, for any $\epsilon>0$, $F(b_i)-F(a_i)=F(i+c_i)-F(i)<\frac{\epsilon}{2^i}$. Note that such a sequence exists due to the right-continuity of $F$. Thus, for any $\epsilon>0$, $\sum_i(F(b_i)-F(a_i)) < \sum_i\frac{\epsilon}{2^i} = \epsilon$. Is this correct?

Comment: @Beerus Yes, that is correct.